# How many people who weren't superheroes did Batman reveal his identity to?

Tags: dc, batman

How many people who were NOT superheroes/supervillains (e.g. excluding assorted Robins/batgirls etc..., or the likes of Al G'uls/Catwoman/Joker) were explicitly told by Batman (or Bruce Wayne) that the two are the same person?

The answer can be either from comics only, OR from comics and other adaptations - I expect the number to be pretty small either way when you exclude superheroes/supervillains.

The only example I can think of would be Gordon from Nolan's Batman movies, and possibly Rachel from the same.

Please note the question is restricted to people explicitly told by Batman/Bruce when they did not know or even suspect the truth; no those told by someone else or who somehow logically figured out/guessed the identity on their own first.

Comment: Does Alfred count? I don't know whether BatWayne told him _explicitly_, but he's in on the secret.

Comment: @sjl - I don't think so. In some continuities, HE tells Bruce to become Batman, and in some, accidentallu tumbles on to the secret when Bruce arrives wounded in Batcave. Neither case fits. Unless Bruce openly tells him in some continuity I'm not aware of.

Comment: @DVK Would Max Shreck from Batman Returns count, or would you lump him in as a Supervillain?

Comment: @Monty129 Sounds like a Muggle to me.

Comment: How many attractive women are there in Gotham? That'd be a good start.

Answer (score 6):

Good question. It would probably be best to start a list.

Off hand:

1. Vicki Vale
2. Silver St. Cloud (I'm pretty sure)
3. Sasha Bordeaux
4. Julie Madison (I'm sure)
5. Harper and Cullen Row, the brother and sister from New 52 Detective Comics
6. Shondra Kinsloving (I'm pretty sure)
7. Jim Gordon (During No Man's Land)
8. Leslie Tompkins

   - A note, the Robins know he's Batman before they become Robin. Every single one save Stephanie, knew Wayne first.

Comment: Tim wouldn't count, since he figured Batman's identity out on his own.

Comment: @SystemDown He actually figures out who the original Robin is, and then by assosiation comes to the conclusion that Bruce must be Batman, but he does need it to be confirmed by Bruce.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, but doesn't he reveal his identity in nu52 continuity?

Comment: How long-standing do they have to be?  There's at least one Golden-age and Silver-age story each where someone in the story was told, but didn't survive to the end.  The Golden-age one was an actor who'd been fatally shot; his last 'performance' was to actively impersonate Batman so Bats and Bruce Wayne could appear together briefly.  Would scenarios such as these count?

Comment: Good thing for Batman that ladies are notoriously able to keep secrets.

Comment: Are "the brother and sister from Detective Comics" you're referencing Harper and Cullen Row ?

Comment: Silver St. Cloud figured it out on her own - she matched the part of Batman's face that was visible to Bruce's, from intense staring during their dates. No, seriously.